# Classes could not be instantiated: Android Studio Rendering Problems API 22

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I create a blank activity layout file assigned to be rendered at API level 22, following error message is generated

[image]

The solution to this is to change the API level by changing it to API 21 or less.

What is the reason behind this?.

Answer (score 0):

This was very common for me when a new API SDK version was released and yes like you mention we have to change the Android version to use when rendering layout in the IDE.

But this time i have installed all the elements described in the Android SDK Manager for this API 22 and I have no problems with the rendering.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just change "AppTheme" to another theme and keep the API level as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Many users are reporting this problem and it happens only in the Layout files that uses support libraries and not the normal ones.